# Getting data from the observable collection to the button event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

```
public ObservableCollection<WordList> MyWordList { get; set; }
    public DictionaryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new DictionaryPageViewModel();

        MyWordList = new ObservableCollection<WordList>
        {
            new WordList { Color = "Red", Letter = "A", Word = "Abdomen", Meaning = "Mean : " + "Mean",Detail= "Mean", Voice = "myVoice.mp3" }
    };
        
    }

    private async void PronunciationButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromAssembly("HERE HERE HERE");
    }
```

I have an observable collection like this and I want to put the voice value in it to the button event below. Thanks for your help

Comment: `MyWordList` is a class level variable.  Just reference it in your `Clicked` handler

Comment: Could you be a little more revealing

Comment: @OneMore If the answer helps you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyWordList` is a class level variable. Just reference it in your `Clicked` handler

```
private async void PronunciationButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    For each (var word in MyWordList) {
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromAssembly(word.Voice);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for your help, but I want to catch all the staff, not just the first guy.

Comment: So you want a loop that will pass each one to PlayFromAssembly?

Comment: Just like that, you are the best

Comment: It helps if you completely describe the problem in your post - see my edit